# return output in JSON format

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I need to get the put of the below code in JSON with out put and request success and request ID.

```
# initialize the SSH client
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
# add to known hosts
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
try:
    client.connect(hostname=json_data["hostname"], username=json_data["username"], password=json_data["password"])
except:
    print("[!] Cannot connect to the SSH Server")
    exit()

# execute the commands
for command in commands:
    #print("="*50, command, "="*50)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
    print (stdout.read().decode())
    err = stderr.read().decode()
    if err:
        print(err)
```

I tried below samples but did not help

```
json.load ((stdout.read().decode())
```

Comment: How does stdout.read().decode() look?

Comment: Wed Jul 15 09:56:57 UTC 2020 (Date command prints like this, my response is printing like this)

Comment: Just remember, in Python, JSON is just a formatted **string**. We use `json.loads(str)` to load a JSON-string to python data containers or types. We use `json.load(fp)` to load a JSON-string from a file-like reference. So you may just do `json.load(stdout)` or `json.loads(stdout.read())`. I could not test your code to confirm

Comment: json.loads(stdout.read())
    
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)


json.loads(stdout)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    'not {!r}'.format(s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'ChannelFile'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed up [`json.load(fp)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) and [`json.loads(str)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads). Either give `json.load` your stdout, or give `json.loads` what you read and decoded.

It happens often to me too, I always check the doc to make sure.